# Cassandra - Update Timestamp column not working properly

Tags: cassandra, timestamp, cassandra-2.0, cqlsh

Trying to update `Timestamp` column in `Cassandra` database.

```
update sample set date='2016-10-21 19:15:10.000' where rowkey=1;
```

When i check the results, it is less than `5:30 hours`.

Output:

```
2016-10-21 13:45:10.000000+0000
```

Is it something to do with `Locale`?, i tried to update the same using programmatically, the same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because cqlsh shows timestamps *only* in UTC as per [CASSANDRA-10000](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10000) in versions 2.1.9, 2.2.1, and 3.0 (beta).  It was fixed to show timestamps while applying the local timezone offset in [CASSANDRA-10397](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10397) as of versions 2.2.6, 3.0.4, 3.4.

If this is an issue for you, an upgrade to a recent version of Cassandra should correct this behavior.

Comment: Thanks, but we are using `DataStax Cassandra version 3.9` not the older versions.

Comment: Is it fixed only in specific versions like 2.2.6, 3.0.4, 3.4?

Comment: @Shankar No, it should be fixed for *after* those versions, too.  But I suppose it's possible that it was reverted somehow.